# How can I plot f(x) with respect to 1/x?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot f(x) on  {y axis} with respect to 1/x on {x axis}?

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way:

```
 ParametricPlot[{1/x,f[x]},{x,x0,x1}, AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, Pi, 3 Pi}]
Plot[Evaluate[Sin[x] /. {x -> 1/x}], {x, 1/(3 Pi), 1/Pi}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are talking about the composite function $f(1/x)$.

Is this what you want?

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, Pi, 3 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[1/x], {x, 1/(3 Pi), 1/ Pi}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[1/x]}, {x, Pi, 3 Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) option, although the ticks also need to be modified to get a decent output:

```
Plot[
    Sin[x],
    {x, Pi, 3Pi},
    ScalingFunctions->{"Reciprocal", None},
    PlotRange->All,
    Ticks->{Table[{n,n}, {n, 4, 10}],Automatic}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To plot y=1/x in Mathematica use the code as below
Plot[1/x,{x,-4,4}] you can use x = -3,3 or -1,1 or whatever you want. 
it solve your problem.