# Raw Object 100.` cannot be used as an iterator

Tags: plotting

There's a similar question here on Mathematica Stack Exchange, however it was left unanswered and the context is  not the same.

I have this code

```
Bcgc = 5.5;
xo = 0.00105;
lambda = 0.2063;
b = 0;

Qs = ((xo/x)^(lambda/2)*E^(-b^2/2*Bcgc))^2;

Plot[Qs, {1/x, 10^2, 10^8}]
```

I want to make a plot of exactly what shows above, Qs x 1/x. However, when I run the plot, it shows this error: **Raw object 100.` cannot be used as an iterator.**

Ways to fix it?

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44940/9490  A basic solution for your problem would be `Plot[Evaluate[Qs], {x, 1/10^2,1/10^8},ScalingFunctions->{"Reciprocal"}]`

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{1/x,Qs},{x,0,Infinity}]` perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

The first argument of the "range" argument in `Plot` has to be a "raw" variable, i.e., not a composite expression like `1/x`.  But if you define $y = 1/x$, and replace `x` with `1/y` wherever it occurs (using the `ReplaceAll` operator `/.`), you can get what you want:

```
Plot[Qs /. x -> (1/y), {y, 10^2, 10^8}, AxesLabel -> {1/x, "Qs"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I still get it wrong, I did what you said, but I get a straight horizontal line in my plot

Comment: @LauraMartins:  Try clearing memory.  The easiest way to do this is to go to the "Evaluation" menu and select "Quit Kernel > Local".  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18562#18562) for more details.

Comment: I got it now, thank you!